# How to save a format like python list in yaml file

Tags: python, windows, yaml

```python
dict = {
    i: [{'cam_R_m2c': cam_R_m2c},
        {'cam_T_m2c': cam_T_m2c},
        {'obj_bb': [0, 0, 0, 0]},
        {'obj_id': 0}
        ]
}
# list = [{'cam_R_m2c':cam_R_m2c},{'cam_T_m2c':cam_T_m2c},{'obj_bb': [0,0,0,0]},{'obj_id': 0}]
with open('./Data_collection/gt.yml','a+') as f:
    yaml.dump(dict,f)
```

I get a yaml file like this

```yaml
0:
- cam_R_m2c:
  - 0.999988853931427
  - -0.0014960498083382845
  - -0.004474445711821318
  - 0.0014844260876998305
  - 0.9999955296516418
  - -0.0025999906938523054
  - 0.004478315357118845
  - 0.0025933198630809784
  - 0.9999865889549255
- cam_T_m2c:
  - 0.014818123541772366
  - 9.016657713800669e-05
  - 0.00015443217125721276
- obj_bb:
  - 0
  - 0
  - 0
  - 0
- obj_id: 0
```

However I want to get this format:

```yaml
0:
- cam_R_m2c: [0.09630630, 0.99404401, 0.05100790, 0.57332098, -0.01350810, -0.81922001, -0.81365103, 0.10814000, -0.57120699]
  cam_t_m2c: [-105.35775150, -117.52119142, 1014.87701320]
  obj_bb: [244, 150, 44, 58]
  obj_id: 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: @Tsyvarev That cannot answer the OPs question as that would leave the last line as `- {obj_id: 1}` flow style and not as `obj_id: 1`. The requested output is not semantically equivalent to the output obtained (even adjusted for the `0` values being different. It is a different data structure altogether.

Comment: @darrenc It is much better to present complete minimal programs here on SO. It makes it easier to see where things go wrong, when we can reproduce your problem without guessing. In this case it also points out which library you are using, as to some reviewers it is not clear that the output you are getting cannot be gotten by the PyYAML (used in the answer they incorrectly mark this one as a duplicate)

Comment: @Anthon: "The requested output is not semantically equivalent to the output obtained" - Yes, so without edit from OP we could only **guess** what part of obtained output the OP wants to change. I wonder how sure you are when post the answer with your guessing and claim that other guesses are wrong.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete post, but the answer below actually solved my problems.

Comment: @darrenxc: If you know that your question post is incomplete, then why don't you fix it? It is never late to edit a question post to the better state. And on Stack Overflow we care of the quality of the posts: a Question/Answer pair should help not only the asker, but future visitors too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- It is unlikely you want to append yaml to a file, use `wb` to open a file or
  preferably pass in a `pathlib.Path` instance, more concise and it opens the
  file in the correct way
- `dict` is a reserved word in Python, you shouldn't mask it by using
  it as variable name
- The officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents
  has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.  [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format looks completely
  different as it an XML format.

The Python list like output for sequences in YAML is called flow-style (the other format is block style, which is the default for output in `ruamel.yaml`)

Then there is the issue that the output that you get is not semantically
equivalent to the output that you want, which you can check if you load that
data. In the output that you get (and in your definition of the variable `dict`),
the value for the key `0` is a sequence of four items, each item being a mapping with a single key (in
Python terms a list of four elements, each element being a dict). In the
output that you want the value for that key is a sequence with a single element,
and that element is a mapping with four keys.

If the requested output format is correct the solution is simple, you have to change the
data structure:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

i = 0
cam_R_m2c = [0.09630630, 0.99404401, 0.05100790, 0.57332098, -0.01350810, -0.81922001, -0.81365103, 0.10814000, -0.57120699]
cam_T_m2c = [-105.35775150, -117.52119142, 1014.87701320]

data = {
    i: [{'cam_R_m2c': cam_R_m2c,  # curly braces removed on this and the following lines
         'cam_T_m2c': cam_T_m2c,
         'obj_bb': [244, 150, 44, 50],
         'obj_id': 1},      # I recommend getting in the habit of also adding a comman after the last key/value pair or element
        ]
}

out_file = Path('gt.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = None  # this makes the leaf nodes flow style
yaml.width = 2048  # to prevent line wrapping
yaml.dump(data, out_file)
print(out_file.read_text(), end='')
```

which gives:

```
0:
- cam_R_m2c: [0.0963063, 0.99404401, 0.0510079, 0.57332098, -0.0135081, -0.81922001, -0.81365103, 0.10814, -0.57120699]
  cam_T_m2c: [-105.3577515, -117.52119142, 1014.8770132]
  obj_bb: [244, 150, 44, 50]
  obj_id: 1
```

If your input is correct and you actually want:

```yaml
0:
- cam_R_m2c: [0.09630630, 0.99404401, 0.05100790, 0.57332098, -0.01350810, -0.81922001, -0.81365103, 0.10814000, -0.57120699]
- cam_t_m2c: [-105.35775150, -117.52119142, 1014.87701320]
- obj_bb: [244, 150, 44, 58]
- obj_id: 1
```

it doesn't suffice to set `yaml.default_flow_style`:

```py
import sys

data = {
    i: [{'cam_R_m2c': cam_R_m2c},
        {'cam_T_m2c': cam_T_m2c},
        {'obj_bb': [244, 150, 44, 50]},
        {'obj_id': 1},
        ]
}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = None 
yaml.width = 2048
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
0:
- cam_R_m2c: [0.0963063, 0.99404401, 0.0510079, 0.57332098, -0.0135081, -0.81922001, -0.81365103, 0.10814, -0.57120699]
- cam_T_m2c: [-105.3577515, -117.52119142, 1014.8770132]
- obj_bb: [244, 150, 44, 50]
- {obj_id: 1}
```

because the mapping with key `obj_id` is now also a leaf node.

To change an individual `dict` to a block style mapping:

```py
def BSD(d):
    ret_val = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(d)
    ret_val.fa.set_block_style()
    return ret_val

data = {
    i: [{'cam_R_m2c': cam_R_m2c},
        {'cam_T_m2c': cam_T_m2c},
        {'obj_bb': [244, 150, 44, 50]},
        BSD({'obj_id': 1}),
        ]
}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = None 
yaml.width = 2048
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
0:
- cam_R_m2c: [0.0963063, 0.99404401, 0.0510079, 0.57332098, -0.0135081, -0.81922001, -0.81365103, 0.10814, -0.57120699]
- cam_T_m2c: [-105.3577515, -117.52119142, 1014.8770132]
- obj_bb: [244, 150, 44, 50]
- obj_id: 1
```

You can also leave the default block style and change the
individual `list`s to dump as flow-style sequences:

```py
def FSL(d):
    ret_val = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(d)
    ret_val.fa.set_flow_style()
    return ret_val

data = {
    i: [{'cam_R_m2c': FSL(cam_R_m2c)},
        {'cam_T_m2c': FSL(cam_T_m2c)},
        {'obj_bb': FSL([244, 150, 44, 50])},
        {'obj_id': 1},
        ]
}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.width = 2048
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which the same result:

```
0:
- cam_R_m2c: [0.0963063, 0.99404401, 0.0510079, 0.57332098, -0.0135081, -0.81922001, -0.81365103, 0.10814, -0.57120699]
- cam_T_m2c: [-105.3577515, -117.52119142, 1014.8770132]
- obj_bb: [244, 150, 44, 50]
- obj_id: 1
```

Comment: Excellent quality answer, thank you.

Comment: @darrenxc As you stated in your other comment, my answer seemed to resolve the problem. If so, please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the V to the left of the top of the answer). That is the standard way for others to see that the answer is useful, without having to read throught  comments.